# Connect xdebug via ssh tunnel remote port forwarding

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I have a home dev machine non accessible from internet, and a public remote web server (vps), both running debian.

On the web server I have xdebug running with output on port 9000.
I checked that xdebug outputs on port 9000 by successfully running on server `$ ./dbgpClient -p 9000`.

I want to redirect it to my local machine as I saw on many webistes like https://derickrethans.nl/debugging-with-xdebug-and-firewalls.html.

On my server I checked my /etc/ssh/sshd_config file :

```
$ cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep "^[^#].*" 
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no UsePAM yes
AllowTcpForwarding yes 
GatewayPorts yes
PrintMotd no 
AcceptEnv LANG LC_* 
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server 
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

From my local machine, after I closed any ssh session to the server, I run

```
$ ssh remoteServer -x -R 9000:127.0.0.1:9000
```

and I get the message `connect_to 127.0.0.1 port 9000: failed.` whenever a php script is run on server.

I checked that port 9000 is not busy on my local machine by running `$ sudo netstat -plant | grep 9000`, there was no output.

Any ideas ?

Thanks to those who read so far...

**[edit]**

in case that helps, here is what's displayed when I run the ssh forwarding command with -vvv option :

```
debug3: receive packet: type 90
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype forwarded-tcpip rchan 3 win 2097152 max 32768
debug1: client_request_forwarded_tcpip: listen localhost port 9000, originator ::1 port 48390
debug2: fd 8 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 8 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug1: connect_next: host 127.0.0.1 ([127.0.0.1]:9000) in progress, fd=8
debug3: fd 8 is O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 8 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 1: new [::1]
debug1: confirm forwarded-tcpip
debug3: channel 1: waiting for connection
debug1: channel 1: connected to 127.0.0.1 port 9000
debug3: send packet: type 91
debug2: channel 1: read<=0 rfd 8 len 0
debug2: channel 1: read failed
debug2: channel 1: close_read
debug2: channel 1: input open -> drain
debug2: channel 1: ibuf empty
debug2: channel 1: send eof
debug3: send packet: type 96
debug2: channel 1: input drain -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 1: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 1: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 1: obuf empty
debug2: channel 1: close_write
debug2: channel 1: output drain -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 1: rcvd close
debug3: channel 1: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 1: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 1: is dead
debug2: channel 1: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 1: free: ::1, nchannels 2
debug3: channel 1: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r2 i0/0 o0/0 fd 5/6 cc -1)
  #1 ::1 (t4 r3 i3/0 o3/0 fd 8/8 cc -1)
```

Comment: I tried with my laptop, also running Debian, same result. Tried through my mobile phone internet access in case my router would be in cause, even if it shouldn't since the data should go through a tunnel, same thing.

Comment: New test, I tried ssh remoteServer -x -R 8085:127.0.0.1:80, and when I query http://remoteServer:8085 in my browser, I get the local web server default page, so the port forwarding works well. So why not with 9000 ?

Answer (score 0):

My configuration was actually working, what caused the error was that I had configured no breakpoint in the sublime text plugin.

Just adding a breakpoint solved the problem.